# AZMAN alternative on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, azman

Ive had a lot of research about authorization on Hyper-V VM's running on WS 2012R2. 
It says, that the tool AZMAN is out of work on this version.

Are there any possibilities for me to controll the permissions for AD Users on VMs?

Cheers 
Logfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - move to claims-based authentication.

Have a look at [Claims : Azman in the new claims-based world](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/04/claims-azman-in-new-claims-based-world.html).

Given that Azman is deprecated as of Windows Server 2012 R2 and may be removed in subsequent versions, it makes no sense to use it.